# How to stop Soft keyboard showing automatically when focus is changed (OnStart event)

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-edittext

I am developing for a tablet using Android 2.2.

I have a form which I am using for new and editable instances.  When editable, I want to stop the user from editing certain fields. I manage this in my `onStart`-event, setting the `txt.setFocusableInTouchMode(false)`.
This forces the focus to the next focusable `EditText` in my form (which is great), but when running, the soft keyboard automatically appears for the `EditText` with the focus.
Anybody know how to stop this?

Here's the code (called in the `onStart` event):

```
private void PopulateFields(){
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txtEquipmentEditTitle);
    AutoCompleteTextView txtMake = (AutoCompleteTextView) this.findViewById(R.id.autEquipmentEditMake);
    AutoCompleteTextView txtModel = (AutoCompleteTextView) this.findViewById(R.id.autEquipmentEditModel);
    EditText txtDesc = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txtEquipmentEditDesc);
    TextView txtDeptKey = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txtEquipmentEditDeptKey);
    EditText txtSerial = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txtEquipmentEditSerialNo);
    EditText txtBarCode = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txtEquipmentEditBarCode);

    txtTitle.setText("Edit Equipment");
    txtMake.setText(make);
    txtModel.setText(model);
    txtDesc.setText(desc);
    txtDeptKey.setText(Integer.toString(deptKey));
    txtSerial.setText(serial);
    txtBarCode.setText(barCode);
    txtMake.setEnabled(false);
    txtModel.setEnabled(false);
    txtDesc.setEnabled(false);
    txtMake.setClickable(false);
    txtMake.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    txtModel.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    txtDesc.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    txtMake.setFocusable(false);
    txtModel.setFocusable(false);
    txtDesc.setFocusable(false);
}
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Put this method in the `onCreate()` method of your `activity` when the activity is first created or called.

Comment: This fixed my problem for the xoom (Android 3.0.1).  I added the above line to my onCreate() method.  I'm still not sure what a "soft input" is.

Comment: Soft input is the onscreen keyboard. The alternative is a real physical keyboard.

Comment: This does not seem to have any effect on Android 2.2.Neither does SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN.

Comment: You can also achieve the same effect by adding android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" on your activity in the manifest

Answer (score 13):

We can Hide the `device Keybord` by following ways which totally depends on the need of situation_

`First Way_`

```
EditText userId;
    /*
     * When you want that Keybord not shown untill user clicks on one of the EditText Field.
     */
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

`Second Way_`
[InputMethodManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html)

```
    /*
     * When you want to use service of 'InputMethodManager' to hide/show keyboard
     */
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(userId.getWindowToken(),
            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

`Third Way_`

```
    /*
     * Touch event Listener
     * When you not want to open Device Keybord even when user clicks on concern EditText Field.
     */
    userId.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int inType = userId.getInputType(); // backup the input type
            userId.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); // disable soft input
            userId.onTouchEvent(event); // call native handler
            userId.setInputType(inType); // restore input type
            userId.setFocusable(true);
            return true; // consume touch even
        }
    });
```

Behalf of all of the above ways_ you can also define `windowSoftInputMode` in application`s`manifest` file_

```
<manifest ... >
 <application ... >
    <activity 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|stateAlwaysHidden"
        ... >
        <intent-filter>
           ...
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

 </application>
</manifest>
```

I hope this will help all!

Answer (score 8):

If you want this for a particular `EditText` this will work.

`editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);`

Comment: required API 21

Answer (score -1):

this is the answer:
In your AndroidManifest.xml add an attribute to the Activity:

```
        <activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity>
```

Comment: I think you missed the question in its entirety, this doesn't hide the keyboard