# How to hide keyboard completely in activity?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

How do I hide the keyboard in the activity and prevent it from opening even by clicking an edittext (programmatically)?

I HAVE ALREADY SOLVED:
I used this code here in the onCreate event:

```
edittext1.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
```

This will disable the keyboard in edittext without interfering with the picker or cursor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop Soft keyboard showing automatically when focus is changed (OnStart event)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221622/how-to-stop-soft-keyboard-showing-automatically-when-focus-is-changed-onstart-e)

Comment: You can disable them all using  `editText.setEnabled(false)`

Comment: @Shermano I want the user to be able to select the text, doing this will not be possible. Anyway, thanks! I already found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hide keyboard in onCreate() method of activity

```
/**
* Hides the soft keyboard
*/
public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
   if(getCurrentFocus()!=null) {
       InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
   }
}
```

or simply use this ("android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden") in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<activity
 android:name="com.example.stockquote.StockInfoActivity"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden
 android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Comment: I don't want the keyboard to open when I click edittext

Comment: Add below properties to the Edittext controller in the layout file

<Edittext
   android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
   android:cursorVisible="false"
   android:focusable="false"  />

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this:

In manifest do the following:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"/>
```

Or in your java code do the following:

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {  
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

Please refer to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard) for detailed explanation.

Comment: I don't want the keyboard to open when I click edittext

Comment: @MahabubKarim Ready!